# ReactJs.net + Redux

Tags: redux, server-side-rendering, reactjs.net

I'm planning to start a project with ReactJs.Net. At work, I work with Asp.net MVC 5 and vs2015. I choose ReactJs.Net mostly because I want to take advantage of it's server-side rendering. I also want to use Redux for managing app state.

Yet, I cannot see many online resources with example of using ReactJs.Net with Redux. Is it possible to go this way? Anyone know some good online guidance I can follow?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this would help

https://github.com/pauldotknopf/react-aspnet-boilerplate

https://medium.com/@MaartenSikkema/using-react-redux-and-webpack-with-dotnet-core-to-build-a-modern-web-frontend-7e2d091b3ba

I hope that helps :-)